# 500 error on htaccess Rule

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My rule cause 500 internal error
Tried

```
RewriteRule ^\/toolkit\/families\-of\-schools\/start\/(.*)$ /toolkit/families-of-schools/start/?school=$1
```

this

```
RewriteRule ^/toolkit/families\-of\-schools\/start/(.*)$ /toolkit/families-of-schools/start/?school=$1
```

what do I do wrong?

Comment: please be bit more specific about what you're trying to do.

Comment: @radex I thought its obvious.I want last part of the url to pass in get var

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is causing 500 internal server error because your pattern is matching rewritten URL also and causing infinite loop.

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !^$
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^.*?(families-of-schools/start)/(.+)$ index.php/$1?school=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Ski you other times also? Also you need to check apache error.log and tell me what is the error there

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30152740/request-exceeded-the-limit-of-10-internal-redirects-due-to-probable-configuratio this error, I have created a topic

Comment: Try my updated code after clearing your browser cache. Also it is not a good idea to create duplicate question for same problem.