# Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error.

Tags: mod-rewrite

mod_rewrite rule throws this error

```
Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

Here is my rules

```
RewriteEngine On
# Removes index.php
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .*families-of-schools/start/(.+?)$ /index.php/toolkit/families-of-schools/start?school=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [QSA,NC,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]
```

the issue happen on

```
RewriteRule .*families-of-schools/start/(.+?)$ /index.php/toolkit/families-of-schools/start?school=$1 [L]
```

I read about and lot saying about some loop but I don't see what loop can be here. Can somebody on fingers explain? The url is

```
/toolkit/families-of-schools/start/ash-green-school-cv7-9ah
```

Comment: Try to remove "/index.php" from problem rule.

Comment: @MaxLipsky did this `(.*families-of-schools/start)/(.+?)$ $1?school=$2 [L]` but not helped

Comment: Try this:

`RewriteRule .*families-of-schools/start/(.+?)$ /index.php/toolkit/families-of-schools/start?school=$1 [L, R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [QSA,NC,L, R=301]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt the problem rule is the rule you pointed out. After rewriting it once, assuming that index.php does actually exist, it should not match again because of the second condition (`!-f`). The second rule however would prepend index.php to the url until eternity.

To prevent future problems, you should also move your redirect rule above all other rules. I recommend to only use **temporary redirects** until everything in your .htaccess is tested and works as expected. Permanent redirects are cached, and if you made a mistake somewhere, any changes you make will not be visible until you go through the painful process of clearing the cache.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .*families-of-schools/start/(.+?)$ /index.php/toolkit/families-of-schools/start?school=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: RewriteCond: bad argument line '!^index\\.php'

Comment: @summurai8 by some reason I am being redirected to /index.php/toolkit/families-of-schools/start?school=ash-green-school-cv7-9ah

Comment: It shouldn't do that. There are no rules that dictate that I think.